# JComponents with Graphics.draw

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to make a simple game using JPanel.

I am using Graphics Draw to display all information, including text, but I need to add user input.

I was thinking about using JTextField with absolute positioning to make it work with what is being drawn, but I have heard that absolute positioning is not a good way set up a JPanel.

Is there a better way to use both graphics paint and JComponents in the same panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: use layout managers

Why not simply have the drawing JPanel held by another JPanel, one that uses BorderLayout and held in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. You can then place JTextFields or other control components in the outer JPanel in other positions.

You can also add a layout manager to the drawing JPanel and then add components onto this using the layout. Just remember that if you add any JPanels on top of the drawing JPanel, the added JPanels should be transparent, that is `myPanel.setOpaque(false)` should be called on them so that the drawing underneath shows through.

For example -- run this program to see what I mean:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class GradientPaintEg extends JPanel {
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
    private JSlider hue1Slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);
    private JSlider hue2Slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);

    public GradientPaintEg() {
        Color color = drawingPanel.getColor1();
        float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null);
        int value = (int) (hsb[0] * 100);
        hue1Slider.setValue(value);

        color = drawingPanel.getColor2();
        hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null);
        value = (int) (hsb[0] * 100);
        hue2Slider.setValue(value);

        hue1Slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
        hue1Slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        hue1Slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        hue1Slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        hue1Slider.setPaintTrack(true);
        hue1Slider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener(hue1Slider, drawingPanel, true));
        hue1Slider.setOpaque(false);

        hue2Slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
        hue2Slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        hue2Slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        hue2Slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        hue2Slider.setPaintTrack(true);
        hue2Slider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener(hue2Slider, drawingPanel, false));
        hue2Slider.setOpaque(false);

        JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 4, 4));
        sliderPanel.add(hue1Slider);
        sliderPanel.add(hue2Slider);

        sliderPanel.setOpaque(false);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // if you want to add the slider panel to the main JPanel:
        // add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(drawingPanel);

        // if you want to add the sliderPanel to the drawing JPanel
        drawingPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        drawingPanel.add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    private class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {
        private JSlider slider;
        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
        private boolean color1Listener;

        public SliderListener(JSlider slider, DrawingPanel drawingPanel, boolean color1Listener) {
            this.slider = slider;
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
            this.color1Listener = color1Listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int value = slider.getValue();
            float hue = value / 100f;
            Color c = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1f, 1f);
            if (color1Listener) {
                drawingPanel.setColor1(c);
            } else {
                drawingPanel.setColor2(c);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GradientPaintEg mainPanel = new GradientPaintEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GradientPaintEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final float X2 = 20;
    private static final float Y2 = X2;
    private Color color1 = Color.RED;
    private Color color2 = Color.BLUE;

    public Color getColor1() {
        return color1;
    }

    public void setColor1(Color color1) {
        this.color1 = color1;
        repaint();
    }

    public Color getColor2() {
        return color2;
    }

    public void setColor2(Color color2) {
        this.color2 = color2;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, X2, Y2, color2, true));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

}
```

In this code example, I have a JPanel that draws, called `class DrawingPanel` and use within another main JPanel, the `GradientPaintEg` class:

```
public class GradientPaintEg extends JPanel {
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
```

If I want to add components to the DrawingPanel, I first give it a layout, and then add the component(s). For instance, there is a JPanel that holds JSliders called `sliderPanel` that I add to the DrawingPanel instance using BorderLayout:

```
drawingPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
drawingPanel.add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

This adds the sliderPanel to the top of the drawingPanel.

But also note that I have to make sliderPanel non-opaque first:

```
JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 4, 4));
sliderPanel.add(hue1Slider);
sliderPanel.add(hue2Slider);

sliderPanel.setOpaque(false);
```

I've also made the JSliders themselves non-opaque so that the underlying drawing shows through:

```
// ......

hue1Slider.setOpaque(false);

// ......

hue2Slider.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: I am using this for some buttons, but it would be nice if the text fields could be on the same panel as the drawings, is this possible?

Comment: @AddisonBallif: yes, again use layout managers. Read and learn how to use them. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).

Comment: @AddisonBallif: but note that if you place any JPanels on top of the drawing panel they should not be opaque

Comment: @AddisonBallif: for example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic mcve of combining user input in `JTextfield` and painting, on a panel using a layout manager:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private final JButton update;
    private final JTextField input;
    private final static int W = 300, H = 350, RADIUS = 100, GAP = 50;
    private String text;

    public DrawingPanel() {

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W, H));
        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        update = new JButton("Update");
        update.addActionListener(e->update());
        add(update, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        input  = new JTextField();
        add(input, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        text = "Enter text and press button";
    }

    private void update() {
        text = input.getText();
        input.setText("");
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        final int width = getWidth();
        final int height = getHeight();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(width/2 - RADIUS, height/2 - RADIUS, RADIUS*2, RADIUS*2);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString(text, height/2 - RADIUS - GAP, GAP);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->makeGui());
    }

    private static void  makeGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawingPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]